# Auto Payslip Printing using Javascript, PHP and MySqli for 500 employees

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I am working on a payroll project and I am coding with php,html,js and mysql on xampp server. I have a salary sheet code which needs to be printed in pdf format for each employee with their names as the pdf filename.

on running the php page the js code triggers automatically and generates a pdf file with the filename as the employee name alongwith the employee salary data.
Now I need to generate all the employee payslips together in this format but automatically or maybe by clicking a single button.

I have done this project in vb6,ms-access with success but I am not well versed in javascript and now I am stuck here.

Any Help will be appreciated

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Salary Sheet</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
include "connect.php";
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM emp_ndata LIMIT 0,1";
$myquery = mysqli_query($con, $mysql);
if(! $myquery ) {
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($myquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
<div id="pdata">

    <table class="table_for_showdata table_for_showdata_small">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
            Salary Sheet of <b class="table_for_showdata_lg">
            <?php echo $row['Emp_Name']; ?></b> :&nbsp; <?php echo $row ['Emp_psmonth']; ?>&nbsp; , &nbsp;<?php echo $row ['Emp_psyear']; ?>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Emp-Code</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Emp_ID']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Designation</td>    
            <td><?php echo $row['Emp_Designation']; ?></td>
        </tr>

      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">EARNINGS</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td >Basic</td>    
        <td><?php echo round($row ['Emp_Basic']).".00"; ?></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td >House Rent Allowance</td>    
        <td><?php echo round($row ['Emp_HRA']).".00"; ?></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th >DEDUCTIONS</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td >Professional Tax</td>    
        <td><?php echo $row ['Emp_Proffessional_Tax'].".00"; ?></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td >Provident Fund</td>    
        <td><?php echo $row ['Emp_Provident_Fund'].".00"; ?></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th >&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="tab_head_blue"><b>TOTAL PAY : </td>    
        <td style="font-size:18px"><b>Rs.<?php echo $row ['Emp_Total_Pay'].".00"; ?></b></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function printDiv() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('pdata');
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1100,height=400');
        popupWin.document.open();
        document.title = "<?php echo $row['Emp_Name']; ?>";
    popupWin.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title>');
    popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
        }
    </script>

    <script>
    printDiv();
    </script>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: I'd use https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ for that. You can generate the HTML with data you need, the convert that into PDF and then send the response to the browser. If you can do it in one file, of course.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus. I will look into it and let you know soon.

Comment: I have seen wkhtmltopdf but that is not going to work with my project. Any other suggestion will be appreciated.